# git-annex use a file from a different location

Tags: linux, git, repository, symlink, git-annex

My understanding is that when I perform `git annex add somefile`, it creates a symlink for that file and places it in the `.git/annex/objects` folder. Then, when I initialize `git-annex` in some different location and sync it with the previous one, it downloads a broken symlink, unless I do `git annex sync --content`, which makes a full copy of the file.

I need to have large files in one location, lets say on a USB Drive, and multiple git repositories that use the large files. So I want to have just the symlinks to the large files in those git repos. How to perform the `sync` so `git-annex` downloads a valid symlink that points to a file in a single location ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that.

First is using hard-links, second is using symlinks. I recommend hard-links if all your files are going to be in the same filesystem/volume/partition, otherwise the good ol' `cp --link` is just going to copy the entire thing.

- Using hard-links:

`git clone --shared main_repo/ new_repo/`

[Explained by git-annex author himself](https://git-annex.branchable.com/forum/share_.git__47__annex__47__objects_across_multiple_repositories_on_one_machine/#comment-aec9b7ac75d79344df8b0e63e88d0106)

- Using symlinks:

On main_repo:
`git worktree add -b branch_name path_to_new_repo/`

Since [git-worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) uses a pointer file (which git-annex replaces with a symlink), this will work across different file systems. Changes to "different repos" will be stored in different branches. If you want them all to remain in sync, keep them in sync with standard git commands like `git merge`. Or you could only make changes to the master branch and `git rebase master` from the different branches frequently.